# rewrite rule code is not working for deep pages

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7, web-config

I write some rewrite rule to manipulate the first folder after domain address as a query string indicating the language.

```
<rule name="en">
<match url="^en/(.*?/)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="./{R:1}/?lang=en" />
</rule>
```

The code above works for first step folders:

```
http://example.com/en/members 
Executes: 
http://example.com/members/?lang=en
```

but not or second and deeper steps.

```
http://example.com/en/members/profile/ 
Executes: 
http://example.com/members/?lang=en
```

and the second step folder (**profile**) is being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Your first rule shouldn't work either, because the parameter `^en/(.*?/)` doesn't match `en/members`, but you can try this rule:

```
<rule name="en">
  <match url="^en/([^/]+)" />     
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.com/{R:1}/?lang=en" />
</rule>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How would you decide if {R:2} exists?

Comment: {R:2}? I didn't understand what you meant, only {R:1}.

Comment: If there was a file name (Or a folder without closing slash ) we would have {R:2} too. e.g en/members/profil.php results in members as {R:1} and profile.php as {R:2}

Comment: Anyway I think `http://example.com/{R:1}/{R:2}?lang=en` would be the general solution. With Regards

Comment: I edited my answer, the previous parameter was unable to match `en/members`.

Comment: The new answer also ignores deep directoreis :(

Comment: Nope, I posted the test results.

Comment: Does not work for `en/members/profile/` . Your previous answer with one time repeating * seems working for all situations:  `^en/(.*)`

Comment: `en/members/profile/` also works, please check the screenshot above. If the parameter is `^en/(.*)`, then when the url is `en/members/profile/`, you cannot get members.